# Display the segmentation of watershed algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, image-segmentation, watershed

I am a newbie to Opencv,
I have recently been using the watershed algorithm,
Currently i have tried to segment the images using different color markers,but i wanted to display the segments as well.

Is there any method by which this can be done, as we can do it in Simple Linear Iterative Clustering super-pixel segmentation using Simple Linear Iterative Clustering function and mark boundaries function

Using Opencv and python.

Thanks.

Comment: scikit image has a library to perform super-pixel segmentation if you are interested

Comment: Thanks Jeru i have tried SLIC superpixel and SEEDS algorithm as well
But i really wanted to know if i could display the segments in the watershed algorithm..

Comment: did the solution work?

Answer (score 2):

First follow [THIS DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html) to obtain the markers in the image. I used the same image present in this documentation.

After that follow this code line-by-line and visualize what each variable contains:

Each unique connected component is assigned a unique value in the variable `markers`. I am normalizing those values present in `markers` to an integer. Each connected component can be obtained at a  particular threshold value mentioned in the list `uniq_thresh`.

```
label_hue = np.uint8(179*markers/1)
uniq_thresh = np.unique(label_hue).tolist()
cv2.imshow('label_hue', label_hue)
uniq_thresh.sort(reverse=True)
```

`prev` is an image having the same shape as the original image but with pixels of value 0 throughout.

```
prev = np.zeros_like(label_hue)
```

Now for each of the unique threshold value in the list `uniq_thresh` I am displaying the connected component. But since `thresh` returns an image having componets above a certain threshold I am subtracting the previous threshold image from it in order to obtain a single component.

```
for th in uniq_thresh:
    print(th)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(label_hue, th, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    cv2.imshow('ind', thresh)
    cv2.imshow('ind2', thresh - prev)
    prev = thresh
    cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```